# NullPointerException TextView setonClickListener when passing intent to MainActivity

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-authentication

I have 2 activities `MainActivity` and `LoginActivity`, There is textview SignIn in `MainActivity` which takes to `LoginActivity` also there is SignUp `Textview` in `LoginActivity` which takes to `MainActivity`, I am getting `Null Pointer Exception` at the line where i am passing `intent` to `MainActivity`.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.tarandeepsingh.test;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.arch.core.executor.TaskExecutor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.SingleLineTransformationMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId,password;
    Button btn;
    TextView SigninTextView;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailId= findViewById(R.id.EmailText);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        password = findViewById(R.id.PassText);
        SigninTextView = findViewById(R.id.signInText);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        SigninTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
....
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId,password;
    Button btn;
    TextView SignUpTextView;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailId= findViewById(R.id.EmailText);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        password = findViewById(R.id.PassText);
        SignUpTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);


        SignUpTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  Exception **LINE NUMBER 37**
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent();
                startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startIntent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(startIntent);


//                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
//                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

logCat

```
2019-12-27 19:35:47.338 29112-29112/com.tarandeepsingh.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tarandeepsingh.test, PID: 29112
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tarandeepsingh.test/com.tarandeepsingh.test.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.tarandeepsingh.test.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is not matching with the id you gave in the xml. Compare the ids.

Also you are attaching the wrong xml in the LoginActivity "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"